# Как в libGDX используя BOX2D добавить текст в экран игры

Tags: libgdx

Известно что, для правильного использования BOX2D в libGDX берутся малые размеры камеры и объектов для их нормальной работы, вот и я взял размеры:

```
game.CAMERA_WIDTH = 20f;
game.CAMERA_HEIGHT = game.CAMERA_WIDTH * Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
game.camera.setToOrtho(false, game.CAMERA_WIDTH, game.CAMERA_HEIGHT);
```

но теперь тот шрифт, который я использовал в меню игры, где у меня размер ширины камеры был 800, я использовать не могу, да и вообще любой шрифт какой бы я не пробовал и какие бы я размеры не задавал шрифту - он получается громадный - одна буква на весь экран. А если мне надо в игре сделать счетчик или подписать кнопки, как мне теперь при таком разрешении `game.CAMERA_WIDTH = 20f;` использовать шрифт? Подскажите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score -1):

Вопрос: Как в libGDX используя BOX2D добавить текст в экран игры.

libgdx - обертка opengl, созданная для упрощения работы с графикой.
box2d - физический движек, не имеющий отношения к средствам вывода графики.

Ответ: никак.

И что теперь делать?: рекомендую к просмотру: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_pwJv1QRSPM&list=PLraIUviMMM3duiko5MtkFPN2vhm0URmkE